# How to Show Image in Jquery-UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery-ui auto-complete and making a  ajax call inside the auto-complete function i am calling my controller action which returns Json , every thing is working fine now i want to show image in suggestion drop down , i am also taking image URL in json how can i show image in suggestion drop down along with Name

**JavaScript**

```
 function log(message) {
            $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
            $("#log").scrollTop(0);
        }

        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetCompanyNames",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: "searchterm=" + request.term,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            alert(item.Value);
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert(ui.item.Name);
            alert(ui.item.Value);
            alert(ui.item.LogoUrl);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });

    });
```

**Action in Controller :**

```
    public JsonResult GetCompanyNames (string searchterm)
    {
        var companies = context.companyService.Query().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchterm)).ToList();
        var list = companies.Select(item => new SearchJsonModel
                                                {
                                                    LogoUrl = item.Logo != null || item.Logo != "" ? "<img  src='/Upload/" + item.Logo + "' />" : "<img src='/home/image?image=" + item.Name + "' />", Name = item.Name, Value = item.InternetName
                                                }).Select(model => (model)).ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**SearchJsonModel :**

```
 public class SearchJsonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Please ask me if you need more detail and thanks in advance .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`documentation`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) illustrates an example of how you could customize the output:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetCompanyNames',
            data: { searchterm: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name,
                        value: item.Name,
                        logoUrl: item.LogoUrl
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {

    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-corner-top');
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all');
    }
})
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append(item.label + '<img src="' + item.logoUrl + '" alt="" />')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```